# Magento 2 - Filter in custom grid displayed in customer view admin tab

Tags: magento2, customer

I have created a custom tab in customer view and loaded grid inside the admin using below link successfully with filter tabs in the grid.

http://www.ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2/magento-2-backend-create-custom-tab-in-customer-view-and-load-grid-inside-admin

But I find an error while filtering on custom data table as I used join query in the collection. Does anyone know how to make filter working for the custom table?

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: It's exactly the same as above link. I just removed "$this->setFilterVisibility(false);" from above code.

Comment: Share screen shot where you getting that error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research in default modules, I came to know that I was missing just one line

```
$this->setUseAjax(true);
```

I hope it helps to someone.

Comment: where to add this line?

Comment: @AliRaza Add it in function _construct in admin GRID block which extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended class